# Object won't construct due to int error even tho they're included in the class

Tags: java

I have a three classes, one to demo and another to extend the first. Everything compiles when in the demo is gives me this error:

```
EssayDemo.java:11: error: constructor Essay in class Essay cannot be applied to given types;
Essay termPaper = new Essay();
                    ^
required: int,int,int,int
```

The four ints are Grammar, Spelling, Length, and Content. I set them up but they don't construct an object properly.

This might have been easier if it weren't for the fact that I have to use two classes that I didn't write. Here are the two specific pieces of code. Here's the essayDemo.java:

```
  /**
     This program demonstrates a solution to 
     the Essay Class programming challenge.
  */

  public class EssayDemo
  {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        // Create an Essay object.
        Essay termPaper = new Essay();

        // Assign scores to the object.
        // Grammer = 25 points, Spelling = 18 points,
        // Length = 20 points, and Content = 25 points.
        termPaper.setScore(25.0, 18.0, 20.0, 25.0);

        // Display the score details.
        System.out.println("Term paper:");
        System.out.println("Grammar points: " + termPaper.getGrammar());
        System.out.println("Spelling points: " + termPaper.getSpelling());
        System.out.println("Length points: " + termPaper.getCorrectLength());
        System.out.println("Content points: " + termPaper.getContent());
        System.out.println("Total points: " + termPaper.getScore());
        System.out.println("Grade: " + termPaper.getGrade());
     }
  }
```

And here's the gradedActivity.java:

```
  /**
     The GradedActivity class stores data about a graded 
     activity for the Essay Class programming challenge.
  */

  public class GradedActivity
  {
     private double score;  // Numeric score

     /**
        The setScore method sets the score field.
        @param s The value to store in score.
     */

     public void setScore(double s)
     {
        score = s;
     }

     /**
        The getScore method returns the score.
        @return The value stored in the score field.
     */

     public double getScore()
     {
        return score;
     }

     /**
        The getGrade method returns a letter grade
        determined from the score field.
        @return The letter grade.
     */

     public char getGrade()
     {
        char letterGrade;

        if (score >= 90)
           letterGrade = 'A';
        else if (score >= 80)
           letterGrade = 'B';
        else if (score >= 70)
           letterGrade = 'C';
        else if (score >= 60)
           letterGrade = 'D';
        else
           letterGrade = 'F';

        return letterGrade;
     }
  }
```

Here's the code I've written to extend it:

```
  public class Essay extends GradedActivity
  {
      private final int grammarPossible = 30;
      private final int spellingPossible = 20;
      private final int lengthPossible = 20;
      private final int contentPossible = 30;
      private final int overallPossible = 100;

      private int grammarGrade;
      private int spellingGrade;
      private int lengthGrade;
      private int contentGrade;
      private int overallGrade;

      public Essay(int grammar, int spelling, int length, int content){
          setGrammarGrade(grammar);
          setSpellingGrade(spelling);
          setLengthGrade(length);
          setContentGrade(content);
          setOverallGrade();
          setScore(getOverallGrade());
      }

      public int getGrammarGrade(){
          return grammarGrade;
      }

      public void setGrammarGrade(int grammarGrade){
          this.grammarGrade = grammarGrade;
      }

      public int getSpellingGrade(){
          return spellingGrade;
      }

      public void setSpellingGrade(int spellingGrade){
          this.spellingGrade = spellingGrade;
      }

      public int getLengthGrade(){
          return lengthGrade;
      }

      public void setLengthGrade(int lengthGrade){
          this.lengthGrade = lengthGrade;
      }

      public int getContentGrade(){
          return contentGrade;
      }

      public void setContentGrade(int contentGrade){
          this.contentGrade = contentGrade;
      }

      public int getOverallGrade(){
          return overallGrade;
      }

      public void setOverallGrade(){
          int grades = grammarGrade + spellingGrade + lengthGrade + contentGrade;
          this.overallGrade = grades;
      }

      public int getGrammarPossible(){
          return grammarPossible;
      }

      public int getSpellingPossible(){
          return spellingPossible;
      }

      public int getLengthPossible(){
          return lengthPossible;
      }

      public int getContentPossible(){
          return contentPossible;
      }

      public int getOverallPossible(){
          return overallPossible;
      }
  }
```

I have four ints in the essay method but they aren't excepted in the constructor. Everything compiles.

Comment: _I have four ints in the essay method but they aren't excepted in the constructor._ How do you figure that? `public Essay(int grammar, int spelling, int length, int content)`

Answer (score 6):

> required: int,int,int,int

The error is telling you that your constructor requires arguments (`public Essay(int grammar, int spelling, int length, int content)`). Right now you are trying to construct an `Essay` , but are not passing any arguments to it.

You need to provide those arguments, or provide a no args constructor:

```
public Essay(){}
```

Or if you wanted to initialize them all to zero and initialize the variables later:

```
Essay termPaper = new Essay(0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Or he can make empty constructor that put all values to 0. Cleaner and better